# Explorer.exe is deadlocked on startup when injecting a DLL

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, dll-injection

I use the registry "run" key to automatically execute my program each time a user logs on to Windows (using *HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run* registry path).
My application starts by injecting a DLL into explorer.exe process, using [Command Line DLL-Injector](http://code.google.com/p/injector/).

The effect should be: Each time after user logs in (after restarting Windows) - My application is executed, and my DLL is injected to explorer.exe

In some cases it works, but in few cases (a matter of timing, rarely reproduces), both the injector and the explorer.exe processes are deadlocked and aren't responding.
I'm not sure, but I believe it happens because the injector is trying to inject a DLL to the process (and suspend it while doing so), while the process is already loading a different DLL (so it's locked). That way both of the processes are locked ==> deadlock.

I know that the deadlock is achieved before the DLL was actually injected to the process.

Does anyone have any idea how to avoid it? Maybe querying the state of explorer.exe before injecting into it? Maybe wait for the explorer to be stabilized? If so - how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Injection is fundamentally dangerous since you are not coordinated with the target. Best is to redesign your solution so it does not require injection.

Comment: You'll probably find it's waiting on your application after starting it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always avoid using a DLL and avoid suspending the target process by rebasing the .reloc section of your executable for injection.